# Receiving error when submitting question

Tags: support, status-norepro, questions

I have seen that this has been encountered many times before, but all of the fixes discussed in previous questions don't seem to be working for me. I am trying to submit a question and am receiving the following error for seemingly no reason.

> An error occurred submitting the question.

Please see my screenshots below and see if you can pick out any issues.

I have tried to slim down the number of characters, and tried logging out/deleting cookies, then logging back in and still have had no luck.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: When I get that I just hit "Post Your Question" again.  Almost always works second time around for me - I've never been prevented from posting, so may be something different.

Comment: Yes, this must be different. I have tried just pressing it a few times in a row and receive the error every time.

Comment: did you include a title?

Comment: Yes, the title is 'Select Layer by Location not selecting features in Arcpy', so it's definitely not exceeding the character limit.

Comment: Is it only the content of this particular text on our particular site that gives this problem? You seem to be able to post to [meta.gis.se].

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a question that you will be better trying to resolve via [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) because it is wider than GIS SE.

To see multiple other reports there type "An error occurred submitting the question" into its search bar.

Alternatively, can you try submitting a minimalist question, and if that works, then build it up until you can no longer save it.